# Is $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ onto when $f(m)=2m−3$?

Tags: functions

I’ve gotten a different answer than the one provided by the professor, and based on how the question is worded and the definition of *onto*, the answer ought to be **no**.

Textbook definition of *onto*: *“A function f from A to B is called onto, or a surjection, if and only if for every element b ∈ B there is an element a ∈ A with f(a) = b. A function f is called surjective if it is onto.”*

This is ℤ: {…, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …}

Both  and () are in ℤ.

If  is onto, then for every element in ℤ, there should be a corresponding  in ℤ that produces it when fed to the function . However, the output of  is only even integers—excludes odd integers. For that reason,  cannot be onto because there are some elements in ℤ that are not outputs of .

|  | () | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | -5 |  |
| ❌ | -4 | no corresponding input in ℤ |
| 0 | -3 |  |
| ❌ | -2 | no corresponding input in ℤ |
| 1 | -1 |  |

Comment: $2m-3$ is *odd*

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: The professor said it *was* onto?  Then professor is wrong as no even integers are mapped to it is not onto.  But are you describing the question correctly?  Is the question "Is $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ one-to-one?" (Answer: Yes.)  Or is the question "Is $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb O = \{z\in \mathbb Z| z\text{ is odd}\}$ onto?"  (Answer: Yes.)

Comment: @fleablood I copied and pasted the question from the practice solutions so I did not add my own wording. Anyhow, I took the exam today making sure to practice by the book since other classmates were also complaining that there were at least 3 other wrong answers to the solutions from the professor…

Comment: If your professor claimed at any time that $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z; f(x)= 2x-3$ is onto and did not have a typo or a slip of a tongue, then you have a fairly serious issue.  That $f$ if *not* onto and it's pretty basic that it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by trying to calculate an (right-)inverse.

We have $f(m)=2m-3$. Now we set $x=2y-3$ and solve this for $y$.

This gives $y=\frac{x+3}{2}$, so the (right-)inverse would have to look like this:

$g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}, m\mapsto \frac{m+3}{2}$, which is obviously not well definied, as it maps only onto $\mathbb{Z}$ if $m+3$ is even. And this holds only for odd integers. With other words, $m+3$ has to be even so that the experssion $\frac{m+3}{2}$ makes sense in $\mathbb{Z}$.

So every odd integer is an image in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not the even integers are not.

Comment: I’m fairly new to inputting mathematical notation, btw. Is there a markup language I need to learn to do things like the y=(x+3)/2?

Comment: It is called MathJax, or LaTeX. You can look it up, or maybe press edit on my post, to see the code. It is fairly easy to pick up, as most expressions have intuitiv names. You can learn it on-demand from several websites, and look for the signs you are missing.

Comment: I just realized I can copy and paste LaTeX from Microsoft Word’s equation editor… guess I’ll hold off learning the mark-up for a while. 

Comment: I would not advice that. Learning LaTeX is pretty simple. It might seem overwhelming at first, but you will get quickly, as it is so intuitiv. At first you should just know how to write fractions, and some special sets like $\mathbb{Z}$, then you will naturally improve over the time. A nice way to find symbols quick, is to draw them: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Our meta site has it's own [mathjax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and I would advise learning it. It's simpler than general LaTeX.